# Extensibility on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures, postgis

I created my own R-tree: "rtree.h"

I want to create an extension in postgres with my own data structure (Using PostGis), already I read about [Interfacing Extensions To Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xindex.html) and now I'm reading some examples [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/gist-extensibility.html), but to be honest, I don't get it at all how can I use my own R-Tree to create an Extensibility, I understand the concepts about operators, indexes, etc, But I don't know how to do it.

> So, How can I connect my file to PostGis and then create an extensibility on PostgreSQL?

Since the extensibilities are functions, let say the one example in PostgreSQL's website:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_consistent(internal, data_type, smallint, oid, internal)
RETURNS bool
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

> How exactly it works? MODULE_PATHNAME is equal to /path/rtree.h?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of how to define a function written in C in postgres you have to compile the object first, so the `'MODULE PATHNAME'` would be `rtree.so` on Linux systems and probably a dll on Windows. The code in the functions directory [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/tree/master/db) provide an outline of the function definitions in C, and the SQL function to declare the function in Postgres.

In terms of how you would implement the R-Tree, I would use the GIST resource that you have already found. I don't think you can just compile your `R-Tree.c` program and it just work, you have to work with the GIST construct. It looks like there [was once](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e7e1694295e3d867f07afedf6505d0e0436cb67e) an r-tree implementation in the Postgres trunk that you may be able to find, or you could have a look at this B-tree gist extension which is in the current trunk: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/btree_gist.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, You are right about the compiling, so first I want to do a little test, however I have some doubts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985683/creating-an-extension-test-in-postgresql) yet.