# Creating an extension test in postgresql

Tags: c, database, postgresql, postgis

I want to create an *extension test in postgres* (Using PostGis), so I want to do the following steps:

1.- Edit the file `btree_interval.c` from [btree_gist](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/btree_gist) in this way:

```
gbt_intvkey_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    intvKEY    *ia = (intvKEY *) (((const Nsrt *) a)->t);
    intvKEY    *ib = (intvKEY *) (((const Nsrt *) b)->t);
    int         res;
  ......
  ......

  printf("Test for PostGis\n");

    return res;
}
```

Only add a `printf`, because I just want to do a little test

2.- Run the following command:

```
gcc -shared -o btree_gist_test.so -fPIC btree_gist.c
```

My doubts are:

> 1.- I don't know where I can find the file `btree_gist.c` once postgresql is installed and then run the command above.

If you ask me: 'Why don't  just you do that downloading the source code?'
Well, because When I did, I got this error message:

```
 #include "postgres.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated
```

So, I thought that it's better do it in the same folder where postgresql is already installed.

> 2.- Once I get the btree_gist_test.so I know that I have to copy to the path `/usr/lib/postgresql/lib/`, but I'm not sure if I have to create a symbolic link to a somewhere else for this file.

Comment: I have some experience in this, but I don't understand what is the probelm. Please tell me which linux distribution is this.

Comment: @iharob My original question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975888/extensibility-on-postgresql So, First I decided to create a little test, by the way: Linux 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu

Comment: @iharob At the first time that I will do this, so If you can help me to create a little extension test, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I don't do this every day but I have an extension in a big project I was working on last year. Let me check that and I will come back to you. By the way, Postgres documentation for this is really bad.

Comment: @iharob I know, I understand the concepts, but following the steps to get success as you say on my humble opinion is not very well documented. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the rest of the compilation error you got... I suspect that's the key.

Comment: Also, sorry for the wacked out answer. I don't know how I got from btree_gist to PostGIS. -ENOCOFFEE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minimal example that works if you have the `postgresql-server` development package for ubuntu installed

**extension.c**
*A simple extension*

```
/* Postgres headers */
#include <postgres.h>
#include <utils/rel.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

static char *
extract_string(text *word)
{
    char *head;
    char *tail;

    if (word == NULL)
        return NULL;

    head = VARDATA(word);
    tail = head + VARSIZE(word) - VARHDRSZ;
    tail[0] = '\0';

    return head;
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(compare_strings);
Datum
compare_strings(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *lhs;
    char *rhs;

    lhs = extract_string(PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0));
    rhs = extract_string(PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(1));

    PG_RETURN_BOOL(strcmp(lhs, rhs) == 0);
}
```

**Makefile**
*A simple Makefile to illustrate how you could build the extension.*

```
CC     = gcc
OBJECT = extension.o
NAME   = my-extension.so
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g3 -O0 -I$(shell pg_config --includedir-server)

all: $(OBJECT)
    $(CC) -shared -o $(NAME) $(OBJECT)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -fPIC $(CFLAGS) $<

install: all
    @install -Dv -m755 $(NAME) $(shell pg_config --pkglibdir)/$(NAME)
    @psql -U postgres -f create-function.sql

clean:
    @rm -fv *.o *.so
```

**create-function.sql**
*A simple script to create the function*

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    compare_strings(VARCHAR,VARCHAR) RETURNS integer AS 'my-extension' 
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

As it seems from your question, you will be able to understand what this does and also how to make it work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to compile most extensions:

In the PostgreSQL source tree, if you've compiled PostgreSQL in that source tree:

- `cd` to the extension directory
- `make` there
- `make install`

... or, if the extension is not directly inside the source tree for PostgreSQL or you want to use it with a different PostgreSQL install, use PGXS.

Assuming that you're using binary packages:

- Make sure that the directory containing `pg_config` is on your `PATH` environment variable
- `make USE_PGXS=1`
- if that succeeds, `sudo make USE_PGXS=1 install`

For more information:

- [pgxs and extension building infrastructure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html)
- [compiling PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html)
- [extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html)